# How do I prevent duplicate message not to be inserted in Service Bus Queue while WebJob processing?

Tags: azure, message-queue, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, brokeredmessage

I want to be sure that if same message is already present in the queue then second message should be ignored (not inserted to queue) while `webjob` is processing first message.

I tried following code:

```
 var namespaceManager =
                NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

            if (!namespaceManager.QueueExists(queueName))
            {
                namespaceManager.CreateQueue(new QueueDescription(queueName) { RequiresDuplicateDetection = true });
            }
```

property `RequiresDuplicateDetection` should ensure about duplicate message.

```
 // Get messageFactory for runtime operation
            MessagingFactory messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

            QueueClient queueClient = messagingFactory.CreateQueueClient("TestQueue");

            BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage();
            message.MessageId = "Localization";
            queueClient.Send(message);
```

But `webjob` gets trigger for every messageId. I gave sleep time 150000 milliseconds but before that I tried to insert same message to same queue, which should not be inserted because of duplicate message.

I tried [MSDN](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Brokered-Messaging-c0acea25) but it is not working in Azure Webjob.

WebJob code:

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("TestQueue")] BrokeredMessage message, TextWriter log)
        {
 log.WriteLine("Webjob Start" + message.MessageId + DateTime.Now);
            Thread.Sleep(150000);
            log.WriteLine("Webjob End" + message.MessageId + DateTime.Now);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate message detection is based on the `MessageId` of the `BrokeredMessage`. The Azure Product Team has a sample illustrating this feature [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Brokered-Messaging-c0acea25).

Comment: This does unfortunately not work :( Duplicate detection checks if SB received a message of the same ID in the last x seconds/minutes and does not check if the message exists in the queue or not.

Comment: Correct: "Enabling duplicate detection helps keep track of the application-controlled MessageId of all messages sent into a queue or topic during a specified time window."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/duplicate-detection